# How do I get a custom domain for my flask site

Tags: flask

I want to get a custom domain for my flask site, I bought a domain already from freenom, and I want to use cloudfare to host it, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you want to pay, [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app) is super easy to use. Otherwise, just google how to host a flask website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used python anywhere to host my app you can just google it!